# how to do i fix this problem Your backup folder MIGHT be visible to the public

Tags: custom-post-types

where do I find this wp-content/plugins/wp-dbmanager  so that I can move the .htaccess to /home/godel09/public_html/mylesmunroemediavault.com/members/wp-content/backup-db

Comment: First, you have written the directory of what you want to find; Second, Why do you want to move the .htaccess?

Comment: Why not just set the proper permissions on the backup folder so the folder is only accessible to you. What you're trying to do is unnecessary and shouldn't be done.